# difference between calling for ... of on an Iterable and on a function that returns an iterable?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any difference between the following two examples:

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.someclass');
for(const node of nodes){
    // do something
}
```

and

```
for(const node of document.querySelectorAll('.someclass')){
    // do something
}
```

Does the function get re-invoked on every iteration? Or are these exactly the same besides the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're exactly the same, except for the extra `nodes` variable name. When the interpreter sees

```
for (const varName of <expression>)
```

it will first evaluate `expression` and then try to iterate over it. It only evaluates that expression once, in an attempt to get an iterable out of it.

```js
const getIterable = function* () {
  console.log('getIterable running');
  yield 'foo';
  yield 'bar';
  yield 'baz';
};

for (const item of getIterable()) {
  console.log(item);
}
```